# How to represent multiples tables with a only model?

Tags: mysql, laravel, orm

I have a very big table and I want to have a table per year. I need represent multiples tables with a only model. I have achieved write in different tables according to the year but I don't know to how read in multiples tables with the orm. Any suggestion? I am using Laravel 5.3

```
class Management extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'management_2017';

    public function setTableYear($date = null){
        if ( is_null($date) )
            $date = \Carbon::now();
        if ($date->year >= 2017)
            $this->setTable('management_' . $date->year);
    }
}

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function saveManagement(){
        $management = new Management();
        $management->setTableYear();
        //... set attributes
        $management->save();
    }

    public function readManagement(Request $request){
        $idManagement = $request->get('managementId');
        // I dont know how to set a table here. Default table is 'management_2017'
        $management = Management::find($idManagement);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess that you can't just put a YEAR field on your table ?

Comment: That is not a very well designed database, @BenjaminBrasseur has a good example of how you can make this solution more future proof.

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur No. the table is very big. To make backup at this moment is difficult. The idea is that on January 1, 2018 the table 'management_2017' be read only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model you can create a method that returns a query builder with the $table attribute updated:

```
class Management extends Model
{
protected $table = 'management_2017';

    public function setTableYear($date = null){
        if ( is_null($date) )
            $date = \Carbon::now();
        if ($date->year >= 2017)
            $this->setTable('management_' . $date->year);
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        $a = new static;
        $a->setTableYear();
        return $a;
    }
}
```

With that, you can use it in your controller:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function readManagement(Request $request){
        $idManagement = $request->get('managementId');
        $management = Management::getInstance()->find($idManagement);
    }
}
```